# help fixing up a regex - \r\n isn't being detected

Tags: .net, regex

Folks,

I have method that returns true if all characters are "legal" and false if a single character is "illegal".  The definition is below (legal = letters, numbers, and some characters like $, - , %, etc).  I want a newline and/or carriage return character to be "illegal".  However, the method below thinks that its legal.  How can I fix-up?

```
  private static bool NameHasAllLegalCharacters( string name )
    {
        var regexAlphaNum = new Regex( @"[^a-zA-Z0-9#\$%\^&\*\(\)\._\-\+=\[\]/<>{}:\s]" );
        return !regexAlphaNum.IsMatch( name );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` matches all whitespace, not just the ASCII space.

Comment: ah!  what do I use for regular-old-space? as in what's between these quotes " "?

Comment: @SFun28 putting a regular space instead of \s does it.

Answer (score 1):

The `\s` class matches all whitespace, and `\r` and `\n` are classed as whitespace.

Your regex will need to be more specific about which types of whitespace are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there're thousands of characters out there (thanks to Unicode) I would not even try to use a blacklist approach. Instead, reverse your logic and test whether all chars belong to your whitelist:

```
private static bool NameHasAllLegalCharacters( string name )
{
    var regexAlphaNum = new Regex( @"^[a-zA-Z0-9#$%........]*$" );
    return regexAlphaNum.IsMatch( name );
}
```

Comment: According to DeMorgan's Law, this is exactly equivalent to what is already there.

Comment: I think there's value in thinking about a large space in terms of what's included instead of what's not-included.  But you are right...they are equivalent

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you're right. I overlooked the double negation, which effectively discards unknown characters.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches this character set: `[\f\n\r\t\v\x85\p{Z}]`. You could simply enumerate this without `\n` and `\r`, like this:

```
@"[^a-zA-Z0-9#\$%\^&\*\(\)\._\-\+=\[\]/<>{}:\f\t\v\x85\p{Z}]"
```

I know it's ugly, but it should work.

Comment: Very cool!  didn't know that.  what's p{Z}?  I found the rest.  none of them seem to be just a space character - i.e. " " (inbetween quotes)

Comment: @SFun28: Very few Unicode character classes match a single character.

Comment: `\p{xxxx}` matches the Unicode named character class xxxx. Class `Z` is whitespace. It includes all kinds of crazy whitespace characters you can find in Unicode like "paragraph separators" and stuff.